# C# Visio Connector. Defining the 'points' of a connector programmatically

Tags: c#, visio

I am trying to use C# to automate some Visio Drawings.  At the moment I am using the GlueTo method to connect two shapes.  However, the auto-routing is not going where I'd like it to.

Is there a way I can manually enter the points that the connector should 'pass through'? (i.e. pass through (1,2), (2,4), (5,6))

I have tried modifying the 'Geometry1' section from the Connector's Shapesheet, specifically the 'MoveTo' and 'LineTo' rows.  As far as I can tell, Visio does not allow this: 
"Operation not allowed for this row type.'"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Few years ago in Russian Visio forum was thread [Invalid coordinate value from a dynamic connector](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?to=en&refd=www.translatoruser.net&r=true&a=http%3A%2F%2Fvisio.getbb.ru%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D6%26t%3D956) (you can read this via [Microsoft Translator service](https://www.bing.com/translator))
**Important**: In [that message](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http%3A%2F%2Fvisio.getbb.ru%2Fviewtopic.php%3Fp%3D9126%26sid%3D4050924088573ad225a30f5c65f851ee%23p9126)

> Solved the problem by adding small pauses (50 milliseconds) after each installation point.
>   Apparently that's enough to worked and co-ordinates Visio logic put out by the faithful.
>   Of course, looks like a crutch, but in this case an adequate

you can find suggest add some delay when you change connector's geometry !

**PS**

> I have tried modifying the 'Geometry1' section from the Connector's Shapesheet, specifically the 'MoveTo' and 'LineTo' rows. As far as I can tell, Visio does not allow this: "Operation not allowed for this row type.'"

If you change row type you break this connector! Connector must have start with 'MoveTo' and few edges with 'LineTo" !!!